# Passing a custom object extending a LinearLayout to another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity where a user can input in a Dialog a name.
 Then a 'BoardElemnt'-Object (its my own Class extending a LinearLayout) containing a textview with the inputed Name and an Edittext, will dynamically added to the Activity. The user can do this as often as he wants. 
If the User long-clicks such a BoardElement he can choose whether he wants to Edit or Delete this BoardElement.
 In case he wants to edit this BoardElement, a new Activity should be displayed where the user can edit some stuff from this specific BoardElement.
My Problem is, im not able to pass this BoardElement Object to the 'EditActivity'.
My BoardElement Class:

```
public class BoardElement extends LinearLayout implements TextWatcher{

private static Context context;
private RelativeLayout parentLayout ;
private LinearLayout fBoard ; 
private TextView txtOutput ;
private EditText editBudget ;
private String fName;
private TextView txtfName= new TextView(getContext()) ;
private EditText editBetrag = new EditText(getContext()) ;


/////////////////////////////////////////
//
// This Data can be Edited in the EditActivity
//

private String fotoPath ;
private String note ;
private String name ;
private String category ;
private String store ;
private String measures ;


//
//
/////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 *  
 * @param context
 * @param _parentLayout
 * @param _furnitureName
 */
public BoardElement(Context _context, RelativeLayout _parentLayout, String _fName){
    super(_context);

    context = _context;
    parentLayout = _parentLayout ;
    fName= _fName;


    category = fName;



    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mparams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10) ;
    this.setLayoutParams(mparams) ;
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL) ;
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.board_element) ;



    LinearLayout.LayoutParams txtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) ;
    txtParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER ;
    txtParams.weight = 1.0f;
    txtFurnitureName.setLayoutParams(txtParams) ;
    txtFurnitureName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.txt_fName) ;
    txtFurnitureName.setText(this.fName) ;
    txtFurnitureName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)) ;
    txtFurnitureName.setTextSize(20) ;
    this.addView(txtfName) ;





    editBetrag.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL ) ;
    editBetrag.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)) ;
    editBetrag.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT) ;
    editBetrag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_field );
    editBetrag.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(9)}) ;
    this.addView(editBetrag) ;
    editBetrag.addTextChangedListener(this) ;       


}
////////////////////////////////
//
// getters and setters 

// ...
```

I tried passing it to the other Activity with `Serializable` and `Parcelable` with no success. I just get my string members passed with the `Parcelable` method, but then i cant edit those member...

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could seperate your class into two different ones. A class which only holds the String properties(`Properties.class`), which can be edited. The other is only to build the layout (`Layout.class`). This way you only have to send the `Properties.class` via Intent to your EditActivity and pass it to the `Layout.class` at the time you want to inflate it. To implement the Parcelable interface for the `Properties.class` should be easy.